# query not using index

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me why this query is not using index idx_accessorieslinkid
I have created index:

```
    CREATE INDEX idx_accessorieslinkid ON `accessorieslink` (actionid);
```

I am new to indexes and trying to understand how they work (and why sometimes they don't!)

sql

```
 SELECT action.actionid
     FROM
      ACTION 
      LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 
  SUM(accprice) AS accprice,
  actionid
FROM
  accessorieslink 
GROUP BY actionid) AS accprice 
ON accprice.actionid = action.actionid 
    WHERE action.typeid = '2'
      AND actiondate2 BETWEEN '20130301' AND '20130301' 
    ORDER BY actiondate2 DESC
```

explain results

```
    id  select_type  table     type         possible_keys                   key key_len ref rows Extra
    1   PRIMARY      action    index_merge  idx_actiontypeid,idx_actiondate idx_actiondate,idx_actiontypeid  4,5 141    Using intersect(idx_actiondate,idx_actiontypeid); Using         where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort  
    1   PRIMARY      <derived2>       ALL   7804                    
    2   DERIVED      accessorieslink  ALL   12175                             Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Answer (score 1):

derived table can not use index on the physical table.

try below query

```
SELECT  SUM(accprice) AS accprice, accessorieslink.actionid FROM accessorieslink 
LEFT JOIN  `action`  ON accessorieslink.actionid = action.actionid 
GROUP BY accessorieslink.actionid
```

Comment: Hi - no change with this solution so removed these sub queries - just LEFT JOINED table and grouped on outer function

        SELECT action.actionid,
        SUM(accessorieslink.accprice) AS accprice
        FROM
        ACTION 
        LEFT JOIN accessorieslink ON accessorieslink.actionid = action.actionid 
        WHERE action.typeid = '2'
        AND actiondate2 BETWEEN '20130301' AND '20130301'
        GROUP BY accessorieslink.actionid
        ORDER BY actiondate2 DESC